# Duplicate named fields using "setResultsName" in pyparsing

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm using pyparsing to decode some frames, but the output of the decoding is showing some duplicate results and I haven't still figured it out why. Here's one example of what I'm getting:

```py
from pyparsing import *

def __Array__(s,l,t):
    n = int(t[0],16)
    buf << (n * asn1)

asn1 =      Forward()
buf =       Forward()

array =     Word(hexnums, exact=2).setParseAction(__Array__) + buf

asn1 <<     ( (Literal("01") + array).setResultsName("Array") \
            | (Literal("02") + Word(hexnums, exact=8)).setResultsName("Variable 1") \
            | (Literal("03") + Word(hexnums, exact=2)).setResultsName("Variable 2") )

structX =   Literal("C1").setResultsName("tag1") \
            + Literal("D1").setResultsName("tag2") \
            + Literal("E1").setResultsName("tag3") \
            + Literal("F1").setResultsName("tag4") \
            + asn1

structY =   Literal("C2").setResultsName("tag5") \
            + Literal("D2").setResultsName("tag6") \
            + Literal("F2").setResultsName("tag7") \
            + asn1

structZ =   Literal("C3").setResultsName("tag8") \
            + Literal("D3").setResultsName("tag9") \
            + asn1

header21 =  Literal("D1").setResultsName("header211") + structX \
            | Literal("D2").setResultsName("header212") + structY \
            | Literal("D3").setResultsName("header213") + structZ

header22 =  Literal("E1").setResultsName("header221") + structX \
            | Literal("E2").setResultsName("header222") + structY

header23 =  Literal("F1").setResultsName("header231") + structZ

header =    Literal("AA").setResultsName("header11") + header21 \
            | Literal("BB").setResultsName("header12") + header22 \
            | Literal("CC").setResultsName("header13") + header23

frame = "AA D1 C1 D1 E1 F1 01 02 02 00 00 00 00 03 00"
frame = frame.strip('').replace(' ','')

res = header.parseString(frame)
print(res.dump())
```

The frame structure is this:

```
AA          -- One of multiple tags : header11
    D1      -- One of multiple tags : header21
        C1      -- StructX - tag1
        D1      -- StructX - tag2
        E1      -- StructX - tag3
        F1      -- StructX - tag4  
                -- asn1 part --   
            01          -- Array
            02
                02          -- Variable 1
                    00 00 00 00 
                03          -- Variable 2
                    00
```

The output that I get is this:

```
['AA', 'D1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1', '01', '02', '02', '00000000', '03', '00']
- Array: ['01', '02', '02', '00000000', '03', '00']
  - Variable 1: ['02', '00000000']
  - Variable 2: ['03', '00']
- Variable 1: ['02', '00000000']
- Variable 2: ['03', '00']
- header11: AA
- header211: D1
- tag1: C1
- tag2: D1
- tag3: E1
- tag4: F1
```

But what I want is this:

```
['AA', 'D1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1', '01', '02', '02', '00000000', '03', '00']
- Array: ['01', '02', '02', '00000000', '03', '00']
  - Variable 1: ['02', '00000000']
  - Variable 2: ['03', '00']
- header11: AA
- header211: D1
- tag1: C1
- tag2: D1
- tag3: E1
- tag4: F1
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
asn1 <<     ( (Literal("01") + array).setResultsName("Array") \
            | (Literal("02") + Word(hexnums, exact=8)).setResultsName("Variable 1") \
            | (Literal("03") + Word(hexnums, exact=2)).setResultsName("Variable 2") )
```

to:

```
asn1 <<     ( Group(Literal("01") + array).setResultsName("Array") \
            | (Literal("02") + Word(hexnums, exact=8)).setResultsName("Variable 1") \
            | (Literal("03") + Word(hexnums, exact=2)).setResultsName("Variable 2") )
```

Group does two things: it creates a substructure within the returned ParseResults, AND it isolates any results names defined in nested parsers.

Comment: Thank you Paul. That second point I didn't knew. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: The up-propagation of results names dates from very early days in pyparsing. I did not want the name structure to be dependent on how the grammar happened to be assembled from smaller bits into larger ones. Adding streamline() reduced the incidence of this problem, but it still crops up. I wanted structuring to be an explicit element in defined parsers, as specified with Group. By Grouping, you can do things like `ZeroOrMore(Group(ident("lhs")+'='+ident("rhs")))` and parsing "a=b b=c d=q" will give you a list of 3 subgroups, each with its own `lhs` and `rhs` fields.